# Edit Properties when an item is selected in my SP list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, modern-experience, list-form

**Problem**:

---

I would like to add a field (called Project Manager) to the properties form, but the edit button is not available as you can see in the picture below, so I draw it.

(I think it should be enabled somewhere but after a long research I didn't found some useful information).

**Expected result**:

---

Add Project Manager to the properties form of the list when a new item is added

**Resource**:

---

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzBqd.png]

What's the best practice function to use to achieve the above result?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using multiple content types in your list? Did you make the "Project Manager" field hidden from content type settings?

Comment: Hey Garesh, thank you for your prompt reply. Actually, I didn't make any modifications to the content type settings because I want to know where I can find it to add this field to display it inside the form library? Could you please provide a screenshot or the steps to add that field on the default Document library form content type?

Comment: When you create a new column, you see **Add to all content types** option where you have to select **Yes**.

Comment: Please find the link I provided that shows the issue while trying to add the column to the "Folder content type", btw is this the right away doing it or it should be on a different content type?  [Error Image](https://imgur.com/a/MfHj1Q8)                                                                                   Looking forward hearing your response and your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: No, this is not a right place. Is "Project Manager" field new in your document library OR it has some data from documents? If new (so you will not loose any data), you can re-create the column & while re-creating column, select "Yes" to "Add to all content types".

Comment: If there is data in column (added somehow using code or any other way), Go to library settings >> advanced settings >> allow management on content types & save. On library settings page, select "Document" from "Content type" section >> Select Add column from library/list >> Add project manager column in "Document" content type (Everything from respective document library settings and not from content type gallery).

Comment: hello Ganesh, I followed your steps but I couldn't find the needed column because the content type is folder not file and the column is not available in the Library content type in order to add the "Project Manager" column [Related Photos to my problem](https://imgur.com/a/TODOwPl)

Comment: Is your default content type set to "Folder"? Do you want to add "Project Manager" column for folder content type or document content type? By default SharePoint library has "Document" as default content type, did you change the default content type in library?

Comment: When I edit the folder properties, in the form I can see the folder content type is selected and I can't find the option to select Document.
In the library advanced settings, the default content is Document. However, I can't find the option to add the Folder content type to the same library and add the column.

Comment: so can you give me if you don't mind a step by step process to make the needed changes because I've been searching for a solution for more than 2 days, I really appreciate it Ganesh, Thank you.

Comment: You can set the default content type as "Document" from library settings page. Under Content types section, select **Change new button order and default content type** >> Set **Position from Top** for "Document" content type to "1" >> click OK.

Comment: Thank you so much Ganesh, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is it working for you? If yes, I will summarize our conversation as an answer below.

Comment: Yes everything is working fine, I really appreciate it, thank you and no problem a summary would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column on list/library form by adding column in content type.

If "Project Manager" field is new (so you will not loose any data), you can re-create the column & while re-creating column, select "Yes" to "Add to all content types".

Else if column is already created & there is data in column (added somehow using code or any other way):

1. Go to library settings >> advanced settings
2. Set allow management on content types to Yes & save.
3. On library settings page, select "Document" (content type where you want to add column) from "Content type" section
4. Select Add column from library/list >> Add project manager column in your content type

---

**Change default content type & order of content types**:

You can change the default content type as "Document" & order from library settings page. Follow below steps:

1. Go to library settings
2. Under Content types section, select Change new button order and default content type
3. Set Position from Top for "Document" content type to "1"
4. Click OK.